# Replace <td> with <tr><td> using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm doing a lazy-ass table transpose here.
I have a table like this:

```
     <table>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">Unique</th>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">x1</th>
     <th style="text-align: left; text-transform: capitalize;">y2</th>
     <tr class="rowNormal">
     <td nowrap="true">a1</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b2</td>
     <td nowrap="true">b3</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

which I need to look like this:

```
     <table>
     <tr class="rowNormal">
     <tr><td nowrap="true">a1</td><.tr>
     <tr><td nowrap="true">b2</td></tr>
     <tr><td nowrap="true">b3</td></tr>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

It only has two rows, one of which is header.
So I hide the header like this:

```
        $("table:contains('Unique')").find("th").addClass("hidden");
```

Which works fine. Now I need to add a `<tr>` to each `<td nowrap="true">`, and here where I have trouble. I use this:

```
       $('div.content').html($('div.content').html().replace(/<td nowrap="true">/g,' <tr><td nowrap="true">'));
```

which works, but I want to narrow it to the table containing "Unique", without using global.
This

```
       $('div.content').html($('div.content').html().replace(/</td>/g,'<td></tr>'));
```

doesn't work at all. I tried playing with `replaceWith` and `replaceAll`, but failed to do the trick.
Questions:
1) The best way to add the formatting to transpose the remaining row into a column?
2) How can I specify `"` and `/` as parameters?
3) What's the difference between `'`and `"`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You probably just need to escape your `/`'s in the 3rd regex.

Comment: have you tried using `$('td').wrap('tr')` ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML you are trying to generate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) in jQuery to do that:

```
$("td[nowrap='true']").wrap("tr");
```

Or for items only with your Unique contains selector:

```
$("table:contains('Unique') td[nowrap='true']").wrap("tr");
```

Comment: Yes that was what I was going to write but nest it inside a $("table:contains('Unique')").each() loop so that it runs only in the tables he wants.

Comment: Wow, wrap is a powerful operator, thanks for bringing it up. However i get and additional empty row to the left? is is from the first tr class="rowNormal"